# Does ready() execute asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a common idiom:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            // some jQuery/JavaScript in here
        }
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
....
```

So we using a JavaScript immediate function which executes some jQuery. Now usually, it is advised to put JavaScript down the end of the page to allow progressive rendering. My questions are:

1. If you are using JavaScript in the head, what difference does it make if you make the function execute immediately?
2. Will `${document).ready(...)` block excution, or does it happen asynchronously?

Comment: It is executed immediately where you put it. There is nothing special about it. `.ready` is executed immediately, of course the callback is executed when the page is loaded. You don't really gain anything by using the immediate function though.

Answer (score 2):

1. It ensures that, inside the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), `$ === jQuery`. Before this script excert, you could have other libraries included (such as Prototype), which have their own definitions of `$`.

   ```
   <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="/Prototype.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () { // error, $ is something to do with prototye

       });
   </script>
   <script>
       (function ($) {
           $(document).ready(function () { // this works fine

           });
       }(jQuery));
   </script>
   ```
2. It is not the execution of `$(document).ready()` that blocks execution, it's the downloading of remote scripts.

   ```
   <script src="/jquery.js"></script> <!-- page is blocked whilst jQuery is downloaded -->
   <script> // This doesn't block the page load
       $(document).ready(function () {

       });
   </script>
   ```

Additionally, I wouldn't call that a *common idiom*. It's common when creating a plugin, but not for wrapping `$(document).ready()` in. The following was created for that, and has the same affect;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { // "jQuery is always passed as first param, alias with `$`
    // Inside here, $ === jQuery
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, it will be fired when the document is done loading and not prevent any other execution.